# Замена подстроки значением из функции от этой подстроки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Например из "`ab(cd)ef(ghi)j`" надо заменить все подстроки внутри скобок значением от некоторой `string funct.f(string)`, где в параметр передается значение внутри скобок.

Например

```
funct.f("cd") == "1cd2"
funct.f("ghi") == "5ghi99"
```

тогда

```
regFunct("ab(cd)ef(ghi)j", funct) = "ab1cd2ef5ghi99j"
string regFunct(string source, Funct funct)
{
    ???
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
static Regex rx = new Regex(@"\(.*?\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static string RegFunct(string source, Func<string, string> replacement)
{
    return rx.Replace(source, m => replacement(m.Value));
}
```

---

Апдейт: передаём в функцию найденную строку без скобок:

```
static Regex rx = new Regex(@"\((.*?)\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static string RegFunct(string source, Func<string, string> replacement)
{
    return rx.Replace(source, m => replacement(m.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

Появилась дополнительная группа в регулярном выражении.

---

Ещё апдейт: получаем ограничители как аргументы:

```
static string RegFunct(
        string source,
        Func<string, string> replacement,
        string open, string close)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
        source,
        Regex.Escape(open) + @"(.*?)" + Regex.Escape(close),
        m => replacement(m.Groups[1].Value));
}

static string RegFunct(string source, Func<string, string> replacement)
{
    return RegFunct(source, replacement, "(", ")");
}
```

---

Кстати, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) предлагает в своём примере более сложный код:

```
static string ComposePattern(string open, string close)
{
    var escapedClose = Regex.Escape(close).Replace("}", @"\}").Replace("]", @"\]");
    return Regex.Escape(open) + @"(.*?)" + escapedClose;
}

static string RegFunct(
        string source,
        Func<string, string> replacement,
        string open, string close)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
        source,
        ComposePattern(open, close),
        m => replacement(m.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Как я вижу в языке моя задача оказывается весьма ожидаемой - решение очень простое. А как сделать так, чтобы заменялась вся подстрока "(smth)", но передавалась в функцию только "smth". Подразумевается, что в качестве скобки может быть другая последовательность символов, да и не дело функции - откидывать скобки.

Comment: @iofjuupasli: добавил группу, сделал ограничители конфигурируемыми.